# Dropdown menu causes scrolling

Tags: css, laravel-blade, tailwind-css

I have a dropdown menu inside one of the columns in a table.  When it is exposed, it is either cut off (overflow-hidden) or created a scroll bar (overflow-visible).

[image: Overflow causes scrolling]

How would I get this to just appear over top of the table (or "extend" a parent div so it's all visible) so that the only scroll bar is the usual one in the browser, not this table-specific scroll bar.  Code provided below.

```
<div class="flex flex-col">
<div class="-my-2 overflow-x-auto sm:-mx-6 lg:-mx-8">
    <div class="py-2 align-middle inline-block min-w-full sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
        <div class="shadow border-b border-gray-200 sm:rounded-lg overflow-auto">

            <div class="flex flex-wrap m-4 justify-between">
                <div class="flex items-center">
                    <div class="beep-label">
                        @lang('livewire.per_page'): &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <select wire:model="perPage" class="beep-input align-middle w-auto inline-block">
                        <option>10</option>
                        <option>15</option>
                        <option>25</option>
                    </select>
                </div>

                <div class="flex">
                    <div class="beep-label pr-2 flex justify-center items-center h-full text-center">
                        @lang('one-word.filter'): &nbsp;
                    </div>
                    <input wire:model="search" class="beep-input" type="text" placeholder="@lang('livewire.search_users')...">
                </div>
            </div>

            <table class="divide-y divide-gray-200 w-full">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="beep-table-header h-full align-middle flex">
                            <div class="align-middle justify-items-auto">
                                <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('name')" role="button" href="#" class="">
                                    @include('livewire.includes._sort-icon', ['field' => 'name'])
                                    <div class="inline-block">@lang('one-word.name')</div>
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </th>
                        <th class="beep-table-header">
                            <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('users.email')" role="button" href="#" class="">
                                @include('livewire.includes._sort-icon', ['field' => 'users.email'])
                                @lang('users.beep_email')
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="beep-table-header">
                            <a wire:click.prevent="sortBy('beep_extension')" role="button" href="#" class="">
                                @include('livewire.includes._sort-icon', ['field' => 'beep_extension'])
                                @lang('livewire.beep_ext')
                            </a>
                        </th>
                        <th class="beep-table-header text-center">
                            @lang('one-word.action')
                        </th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="bg-white divide-y divide-gray-200">
                    @foreach ($contacts as $contact)
                    <tr @if ($contact->is_active !== true) class="table-danger" @endif>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                            <div class="flex items-center">
                                <div class="flex-shrink-0 h-10 w-10">
                                    @if ($contact->contactable->thumbnail)
                                        <img class="h-10 w-10 rounded-full"
                                            src="{{ $contact->contactable->thumbnail }}"
                                            alt="">
                                    @else
                                        <x-nav.svg-icons icon="user-circle" class="w-3 h-3" />
                                    @endif
                                </div>
                                <div class="ml-4">
                                    <div class="text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-900">
                                        {{ $contact->name }}
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-500">{{ $contact->contactable->email }}</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                            <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900">{{ $contact->beep_mail }}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap">
                            <div class="text-sm leading-5 text-gray-900">{{ $contact->beep_extension }}</div>
                        </td>
                        <td class="px-6 py-4 whitespace-no-wrap text-center text-sm leading-5 font-medium">
                            <div x-data="{ open: false }" @keydown.window.escape="open = false" @click.away="open = false" class="relative inline-block text-left">
                                <div>
                                  <span class="rounded-md shadow-sm">
                                    <button @click="open = !open" type="button" class="inline-flex justify-center w-full rounded-md border border-gray-300 px-4 py-2 bg-white text-sm leading-5 font-medium text-gray-700 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-300 focus:shadow-outline-blue active:bg-gray-50 active:text-gray-800 transition ease-in-out duration-150" id="options-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                                      @lang('one-word.action')
                                      <!-- Heroicon name: chevron-down -->
                                      <svg class="-mr-1 ml-2 h-5 w-5" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="currentColor">
                                        <path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M5.293 7.293a1 1 0 011.414 0L10 10.586l3.293-3.293a1 1 0 111.414 1.414l-4 4a1 1 0 01-1.414 0l-4-4a1 1 0 010-1.414z" clip-rule="evenodd" />
                                      </svg>
                                    </button>
                                  </span>
                                </div>
                                <div x-show="open" x-description="Dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state." x-transition:enter="transition ease-out duration-100" x-transition:enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95" x-transition:enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave="transition ease-in duration-75" x-transition:leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100" x-transition:leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95" class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-10">
                                  <div class="rounded-md bg-white shadow-xs">
                                    <div class="py-1" role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="options-menu">
                                        @can ('view', $contact->contactable)
                                            <a href="{{ route('users.show', $contact->contactable) }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">@lang('users.view_profile')</a>
                                        @endcan
                                        @can ('update', $contact->contactable)
                                        <a href="{{ route('users.edit', $contact->contactable) }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">@lang('one-word.edit')</a>
                                            <a href="{{ route('contacts.methods.index', $contact->contactable) }}" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">@lang('livewire.edit_contact_methods')</a>
                                            <a href="#" wire:click="deactivate({{ $contact->id }})" class="block px-4 py-2 text-sm leading-5 text-gray-700 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-gray-900 focus:outline-none focus:bg-gray-100 focus:text-gray-900" role="menuitem">{{ $contact->is_active ? __('one-word.deactivate') : __('one-word.activate') }}</a>
                                        @endcan
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>

                <div class="p-2 uppercase text-sm bg-gray-200">
                    {{ $contacts->links() }}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the extracted css components in case they are helpful:

```
.beep-label {
    @apply block uppercase tracking-wide text-gray-700 text-xs font-bold mb-2;
}

.beep-input {
    @apply appearance-none block w-full text-gray-700 border border-gray-500 rounded py-1 px-2 mb-3;
}

.beep-table-header {
    @apply px-6 py-3 bg-gray-100 text-left text-xs leading-4 font-medium text-gray-500 uppercase tracking-wider;
}
```

Comment: I believe you need to use position: absolute; for the dropdown menu

Comment: The dropdown does have absolute right now:  class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-56 rounded-md shadow-lg z-10"

Comment: You're looking to do something like this [article](https://css-tricks.com/popping-hidden-overflow/) shows. You should also use Javascript to determine whether the dropdown should drop down or up based on the screen position of the line item interacted with. But in my opinion you could save yourself a lot of headache with a modal as opposed to a dropdown.